# Set a constant in an object

Tags: javascript, oop, constants

I want to set one of the properties of my object as a constant. How can I do this using `property: value` notation?

```
var Hero = {
  name: "Vasilli Zeitsev",
  occupation: "sniper"
}
```

I want the name to be a constant, but doing `name: const 'Vasilli Zeitsev'` seems to error.

FYI: [Javascript constants](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Comment: Use `Object.defineProperty` to not allow it to be writeable. Straight from the link you provided: `Creates a constant that can be global or local to the function in which it is declared.` - I don't see anything about object properties

Answer (score 1):

`const: Implemented in JavaScript 1.5, NES 6.0 (Netscape extension,` [C engine only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey)`)`.

If you need to define a read-only property in an object literal, you could try a [`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get):

```
var Hero = {
  get name() {return "Vasilli Zeitsev"},
  occupation: "sniper"
}
```

Comment: It looks like [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) can override a getter value, so it's not bullet proof...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're targeting newer browsers:
you can use 'Object.defineProperty' to set something to non-writable.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

```
Object.defineProperty(Hero, name, {value: "Vasilli Zeitsev", writable: false})
```

Comment: definePeroperties might be relevant as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2FdefineProperties

Comment: is a six-year-old browser still considered "newer"?

Comment: @dandavis The OP is trying to use `const`. I'd assume `Object.defineProperty` is available in the same browser

Comment: You can omit `writable: false`, it's false by default.